# Show that $k \bigtriangleup T+ \nabla k \cdot \nabla T=0$ leads to $\bigtriangleup (k^{1/2} T)- \frac{\bigtriangleup(k^{1/2})}{k^{1/2}}k^{1/2}T=0$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to see the following derivation given in the book '*Kernel Functions and Elliptic Differential Equation in Mathematical Physics*' by S. Bergman and M. Schiffer. We deduced the differential equation 
$$k \bigtriangleup T+ \nabla k \cdot \nabla T=0$$
Here $k=k(x,y,z)\ge 0$ is the heat conduction coefficient and $T=T(x,y,z)$ is the temperature at $(x,y,z)$. Now the book says that if we divide by $k^{1/2}$ and use the identity $\bigtriangleup (UV) = U\bigtriangleup V + 2\nabla U \cdot \nabla V + V \bigtriangleup U $ we can show that this reduces to 
$$\bigtriangleup (k^{1/2} T)- \frac{\bigtriangleup(k^{1/2})}{k^{1/2}}k^{1/2}T=0.   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\quad\quad\ \ \ (*)$$

So starting with the first equation and dividing by $k^{1/2}$ as suggested and rearranging to get
$$k^{1/2} \bigtriangleup T =- \frac{1}{k^{1/2}}\nabla k \cdot \nabla T.$$
Now the given identity can be rewritten as $\nabla U \cdot \nabla V = \frac{1}{2} \left\{   \bigtriangleup (UV) - U\bigtriangleup V - V \bigtriangleup U     \right\} $, we use this to rewrite the right side of the last equation.
$$k^{1/2} \bigtriangleup T   =- \frac{1}{2k^{1/2}}  \left\{  \bigtriangleup(kT)-k\bigtriangleup T - T\bigtriangleup k   \right\} =\frac{ -\bigtriangleup(kT)+ T\bigtriangleup k  }{2k^{1/2}}  + \frac{k^{1/2}\bigtriangleup T}{2} .  $$
Now slight rearrangement gives
$$k^{1/2}\bigtriangleup T =  \frac{ -\bigtriangleup(kT)+ T\bigtriangleup k  }{k^{1/2}}    $$
Now from here I do not know how to continue. I think I might have taken a less then optimal route to get to the answer but I think it should work somehow. Now it is curious that equation $(*)$ has a factor $\frac{k^{1/2}}{k^{1/2}}$ that can just be cancelled but there is a reason for this. Upon making the change $T^* =k^{1/2}T $ we get the equation
$$\bigtriangleup T^*=a(x,y,z)T^*,\quad \quad \bigtriangleup k^{1/2} = a(x,y,z)k^{1/2}$$
If anyone could help me finish up the argument to show the equivalence of the first two equations that would be a great help. Of course other approaches of solving would be very welcome to. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta(k^{1/2} T) = k^{1/2} \Delta T + 2 \nabla T \cdot \nabla k^{1/2} + T \Delta k^{1/2}$.  Now $\nabla k^{1/2} = \frac12 k^{-1/2} \nabla k$.  So we get $\Delta (k^{1/2} T) = k^{-1/2}(k \Delta T + \nabla T \cdot \nabla k) + T \Delta k^{1/2} = T \Delta k^{1/2}$.